# Executing two commands in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to separately run server and client on the port number 19345, but I want to compile them all at once by simply typing `make` using `Makefile`. To do so, I created the following `Makefile`:

```
target: run_server run_client

run_server:
    ./server 19345
         
run_client:
    ./client 19345

server: server.c
    gcc -o server.c

client: client.c
    gcc -o client.c

clean:
    rm *.o run_server run_client target
```

Unfortunately, when I typed `make`, the terminal result shows as follows:

```
./server 19345
make: ./server: Command not found
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'run_server' failed
make: *** [run_server] Error 127
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Make your `run_*` targets depend on the executables they run...? Otherwise they can/will try to run those commands first, which obviously doesn't work if they don't exist, and even if they still existed from a previous build would thus use outdated binaries.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just do:

```
.PHONY: target run_server run_client
target: run_server run_client

run_server: server
    ./server 19345
         
run_client: client
    ./client 19345

clean:
    rm -f *.o server client
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems when I type `make`, it automatically runs `/server 19345`, which limits me to run `client 19345` separately. Is there any way to run server and client by using two different commands (such as typing `./server` and `./client` after I run `make`)?

Comment: Do you mean that `server` does not run asynchronously?  If the server does not detach itself and run as a server, you should make it do so.  As it stands, there is no reason you cannot run `./server` and `./client` after you build them with make.

Comment: But note that this is really an abuse of `make`.  If you want to run the two programs in parallel, you really ought to just run a script along the lines of `./server & ./client &`.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. :)